# How to change values with only one occurrence? (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a sample dataframe like this, with val being a binary value (between 1 and 2 in this instance). I would like to eliminate outliers in val, changing them to be the same as the majority value.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'name':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'val':[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})

   name  val
0     A    1
1     A    2
2     A    2
3     A    2
4     B    2
5     B    1
6     B    1
7     B    1
8     C    1
9     C    1
10    C    2
11    C    2
```

I would like the values at indexes 0 and 4 to be corrected (to 2 and 1 respectively, here), as there is only one occurrence in each group, but C to be unaltered.

I think I could write a transform statement, but not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Why would the `2` in `B` be left alone?

Comment: @roganjosh OP clearly says that it should not. _"I would like the values at indexes 0 and 4 to be corrected"_

Comment: "to be corrected"  - to what value?

Comment: ok, so the group with `[A A A A] and [1 2 3 3]` should eventually contain `[3 3 3 3]`

Comment: If you have a group with (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), the output would be (3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3) or (3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest To the opposite value, or value of "majority", as the data I'm working with only has two possible values. Essentially ensuring that within each group, outliers with a single occurrence are eliminated. Edited post to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote you only have two possible values, you can compare the count of each value:

```
def fix_outliers(sr):
    cnt = sr.value_counts()
    return sr if cnt.iloc[0] == cnt.iloc[1] else [cnt.index[0]]*len(sr)

out = df.groupby('name')['val'].transform(fix_outliers)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
0     2
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    2
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the value that occurs most times you can use [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) to find this values, than you can check if the `count` of `mode` is equal to 1. In case it is not equal to 1 that means that has two or more values happen in the same frequency.

```
for name in df["name"].unique(): #find distinct names in df
    if(df[(df["name"] == name)].mode()["val"].count() == 1): #check if mode is sized 1
        most_common_value = df[(df["name"] == name)].mode()["val"][0] # find the mode
        df.loc[df["name"] == name , "val"] = most_common_value # modify df to val be the mode
```

Output:

```
  name val
0   A   2
1   A   2
2   A   2
3   A   2
4   B   1
5   B   1
6   B   1
7   B   1
8   C   1
9   C   1
10  C   2
11  C   2
```